# What's wrong with my tail-recursive sum procedure?

Tags: sum, scheme, tail-recursion

What's wrong with my tail-recursive sum procedure? My tail-recursive scheme procedure will not run.

Code:

```
(define (sum term a next b)
    (define iter result i) 
        (if (> i b)
            result
        (iter (+ result (term i)) (next i))
        (iter 0 a )))

 (define (increment x)(+ x 1))

 (define (sum-square a b)

    (sum (lambda(x)(* x x)) a increment b))

 (define (sum-int a b)
    (define (identity a) a)

    (sum identity a increment b))


(sum-int 5 10)
(sum-square 5 10)
```

Error:

```
Error: execute: unbound symbol: "result" [sum-int, (anon), sum, (anon), sum-square, sum, (anon)]
```

Comment: Did you get an error message?  What does "it won't run" mean?  I see you've already accepted an answer, but the form of it suggests that you probably should have been getting a compilation error in the first place.  Please include it in the question so that it's something that other users could find if they were searching for a solution to a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have parentheses problems in `sum`. Try this:

```
(define (sum term a next b)
  (define (iter result i)
    (if (> i b)
        result
        (iter (+ result (term i)) (next i))))
  (iter 0 a))
```

In particular, notice that this line was wrong, that's not how you define a procedure:

```
(define iter result i)
```

And the corresponding closing parentheses is wrong, too. A strict discipline of correctly indenting and formatting the code will make these kind of errors easier to catch, use a good IDE for this.

Comment: Thanks! Which ide do you use?

Comment: Racket, with a generous amount of Ctrl+i ("Reindent All") and "Check Syntax" :)